# Why <video> only loads after all other elements have finished loading?

Tags: html, video

I've got an 8-second video in progressive mp4, and it's only 1.3 mb. I want to use it as a full-screen background.

It is expected to play automatically when page beginning to load. But it seems that it can be loaded only after all other elements have finished loading. How to solve this problem?

My page layout is like the followings, just a very simple one:

```
<nav></nav>
<video src="" autoplay loop></video>
<div></div>
...
<div></div>
<footer></footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_video.asp), you have to specify the optional attribute `preload` if you think the video should be loaded when the page loads.

Moreover, it seems like this optional attribute is **not** supported on Windows Edge, so pay attention.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But it also says 'The preload attribute is ignored if autoplay is present.' In my case, the video is set to autoplay...